# Time evolution of a finite dim. quantum system

Tags: hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

> We will study the time-evolution of a finite dimensional quantum system. To this end, let us consider a quantum mechanical system with the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$. We denote by $\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$ and $\left . \left |   1  \right \rangle\right .$ the standard basis elements $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$. Let the Hamiltonian of the system in this basis be given by
> $$
> H=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &-i \\ 
> -i &0 
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> and assume that for $t=0$ the state of the system is just given by $\psi(t=0)=\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$. In the following, we also assume natural units in which $\hbar=1$.

**Problems**:

> a) Determine the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and the normalized eigenvectors $f_i$ of $H$.
>
> b) Compute the time evolution operator $U(t)=e^{-iHt}$ of the system, according to $f(H)=\sum_{i=1}^{2}f(\lambda_i)\left . \left |   e_i  \right \rangle\right . \left \langle \left . e_i \right | \right .$
> for $f$ and analytic function for all $\lambda_i$. Compute the time evolved state $\psi(t)=U(t)\psi(t=0)$.

I do not understand what to do for problem b). I need help for this one. For a), I found out that the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are $\pm 1$, and the normalized eigenvectors $f_i$ are $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}
-i\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You need to diagonalize $H$. If you can write $H=PDP^{-1},$ with $D$ diagonal and $P$ orthogonal, then it's much more straight-forward to take the matrix exponential $e^{-iHt}:\;e^{-iHt}=e^{-iPDP^{-1}t}=Pe^{-iDt}P^{-1}.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thank you for your comment. I figured out that 
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\ 0&-i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track!

Comment: @AdrianKeister That's good to know. I'm still confused to what exactly I am doing. What connection does it have with the $f(H)$? I apologize if the questions seem easy as I am kind of new to this subject.

Comment: The formula given for $f(H)$ corresponds to my $e^{-iHt}=Pe^{-iDt}P^{-1},$ because you can essentially act on the eigenvalues of the matrix instead of on the matrix itself, once you've diagonalized it. The entries on the diagonal matrix $D$ *are* the eigenvalues.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I see, I realized I made mistakes determining the eigenvalues $\pm 1$ instead of $\pm i$. Is it true that $$U(t)=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-t}+e^{t} & e^{-t}-e^{t}\\ 
e^{-t}-e^{t} & e^{-t}+e^{t}
\end{pmatrix}?
$$
I Used Wolfram Alpha to calculate  $\quad$
[[-1,1],[1,1]].[[exp(t),0],[0,exp(-t)]]. [[-1/2,1/2],[1/2,1/2]] $\quad$.
Can you help me with the last problem?

Comment: Try the `MatrixExp` function in Mathematica - I don't know if W|A will execute that one. You can go all the way from $H$ to $e^{-iHt}$ using that one function!

Comment: @AdrianKeister I tried it with Maple and it agrees with Wolfram Alpha. In order to answer the last one, I should just multiply this matrix $U(t)$ with $(1,0)^{T}$, right?

Comment: Yep, exactly right!

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: You're very welcome!