# Time evolution of a finite dim. quantum system part 2

Tags: hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

This is an extension to the previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095092/time-evolution-of-a-finite-dim-quantum-system).

> We will study the time-evolution of a finite dimensional quantum system. To this end, let us consider a quantum mechanical system with the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$. We denote by $\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$ and $\left . \left |   1  \right \rangle\right .$ the standard basis elements $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$. Let the Hamiltonian of the system in this basis be given by
>   $$
> H=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &-i \\ 
> -i &0 
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   and assume that for $t=0$ the state of the system is just given by $\psi(t=0)=\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$. In the following, we also assume natural units in which $\hbar=1$.

**Problems**:

> i) Compute the expectation value of a $Z$-measurement at time $t$: $\left \langle \sigma_z \right \rangle_{\psi(t)}=\left \langle \psi(t)\mid \sigma_z\psi(t) \right \rangle$, where $$
> \sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &0 \\ 
> 0 &-1 
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> ii) Instead of evolving the quantum states in time, we can alternatively
>   evolve the observables according to $\sigma_z(t)=e^{iHt}\sigma_ze^{-iHt}$, called the Heisenberg evolution of $\sigma_z$. At which time should we perform our measurement in order to maximize the expectation value of $\sigma_z$?

In the previous post, I've concluded that
$$
\psi(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\ 
-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I am not really sure how to calculate $\left \langle \psi(t)\mid \sigma_z\psi(t) \right \rangle$. Can you help me with this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your $\psi(t)$ is correct, you need to perform this:
\begin{align*}
\langle\psi(t)|\sigma_z\,\psi(t)\rangle &=\left\langle\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t} \end{matrix}\right]\Bigg|\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t} \end{matrix}\right]\right\rangle \\
&=\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}&-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t} \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\\frac{1}{2}e^{t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t} \end{matrix}\right],
\end{align*}
and so on. You know, this would likely be a bit easier using hyperbolic trig functions:
\begin{align*}
\langle\psi(t)|\sigma_z\,\psi(t)\rangle &=\left\langle\left[\begin{matrix}\cosh(t)\\-\sinh(t) \end{matrix}\right]\Bigg|\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cosh(t)\\-\sinh(t) \end{matrix}\right]\right\rangle \\
&=\left[\begin{matrix}\cosh(t)&-\sinh(t) \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cosh(t)\\\sinh(t)\end{matrix}\right] \\
&=\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)\\
&=1,
\end{align*}
somewhat miraculously.

Comment: May I know which definition of $<.|.>$ you used to calculate it?

Comment: In QM, the usual inner product is that for vectors $|\psi\rangle, \; |\varphi\rangle,$ you have $\langle \varphi|\psi\rangle=|\varphi\rangle^{\dagger}\cdot|\psi\rangle$. So you take the complex conjugate transpose of the first vector, and dot it into the second.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have time to help me with the last problem?

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the second part. The Heisenberg picture and the Schrödinger picture are equivalent, and we just calculated the expected value of $\sigma_z$ to be a constant: $1$. If it's not varying in time, I don't see how the time matters. I would just answer that the time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate

$$
\sigma_z |\psi(t)\rangle = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1} \pmatrix{\cosh t \\ -\sinh t } =  \pmatrix{\cosh t \\ \sinh t }
$$

And then

$$
\langle \psi(t)|\sigma_z |\psi(t)\rangle = \pmatrix{\cosh t & -\sinh t} \pmatrix{\cosh t \\ \sinh t } = \cosh^2 t - \sinh^2t = 1
$$